# array_diff_key catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string?

Tags: php, arrays

**VOTE TO CLOSE. COMPLETLY MISSPELLED METHOD. THANKS AND SORRY FOR BOTHER.**

I'm getting an error `array_diff_key`to an array of objects. Is this a bug or something? This isn't supposed to happen:

```
array array_diff_key ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

> Compares the keys from array1 against the keys from array2 and returns
>   the difference. This function is like array_diff() except the
>   comparison is done on the keys instead of the values.

```
echo "all:";
var_dump($all);
echo "filtered:"
var_dump($filtered);
$not_valid = array_diff_key($all, $filtered);

all:
array
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]

filtered:
array
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
```

**Result**:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string.

**EDIT**: a simple example that actually works using `sdtClass` (so.. why my code above isn't working?):

```
$all = array(
    1 => (object) array('name' => 'Apple'),
    2 => (object) array('name' => 'Banana'),
    3 => (object) array('name' => 'Meat'),
);

$animal = array(3 => (object) array('name' => 'Meat'));
$vegetable = array_diff_key($all, $animal);

var_dump($vegetable);
```

**EDIT 2**: if matters, this is how actually `$all` array is built (`$all = fetchHeaders()`):

```
$all = fetchHeaders();
array_diff_assoc($all, array(1 => new stdClass())) // Fatal error

public function fetchHeaders()
{
    $retval = array();
    $last = @imap_num_msg($this->conn);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $last; $i++)
    {
        $header = @imap_header($this->conn, $i);
        $uid    = @imap_uid($this->conn, intval(trim($header->Msgno)));
        $parsed =  MIMEParser::decodeHeader($header);
        if($parsed) $retval[$uid] = $parsed;
    }
    return $retval;
}

public static function decodeHeader($header)
{
    $person  = isset($header->from[0]->personal) ?
         trim($header->from[0]->personal) : null;
    $subject = isset($header->subject) ? trim($header->subject) : null;

    $retval = array(
        'date'    => $header->udate,
        'from'    => $header->from[0]->mailbox . '@' . $header->from[0]->host,
        'person'  => !empty($person) ? $person : null,
        'to'      => $header->to[0]->mailbox . '@' . $header->to[0]->host,
        'subject' => !empty($subject) ? $subject : null,
    );
    return (object) $retval;
}
```

Comment: what is the definition of your stdClass??

Comment: works fine with my php5.3.5/win32. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Laurence Burke: stdClass is built-in, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php

Comment: @LaurenceBurke it's a simple cast to object from an associative array. Each stdClass object is then added to `$all`.

Comment: Could be using a custom version of stdClass. Dont assume

Comment: @VolkerK PHP Version 5.3.8 windows 7 x64.

Comment: @Laurence Burke: no, that would result in a `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class StdClass` ;-)

Comment: @all Found more documentation that may prove useful for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please insert this snippet

```
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler', E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    $db = debug_backtrace();
    echo "\n\n----------------\n", $db[1]['function'], "\n";
    var_dump($db[1]['args']);

    foreach( $db as $f ) {
        echo $f['function'], "\n";
    }

    $c = file($errfile);
    echo $c[$errline-1], "\n--------------------\n";

    return false;
}
```

somewhere in the script where it is executed before the error occurs and then add the output to your question text?

Comment: here is it: http://pastebin.com/0siAmmhT (i've just removed real addresses in ojbect properties). Thank you for helping.

Comment: And the winner is: `array_diff_assoc` which is not `array_diff_key` ;-) `$invalid = array_diff_assoc($all_headers, $valid_headers);`

Comment: And the winner is... i'm an asshole. Please vote to delete this question. And thanks. I'm been working so hard, i just need to rest.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce using the following snippet:

```
$aArray = array_diff_key(
    array(
        0 => new stdClass(),
        1 => new stdClass()
    ), 
    array(
        2 => new stdClass(),
        1 => new stdClass()
    )
);
```

The error you receive is **typical** for array_diff, please check your function name.

Comment: Double checked, thanks for helping but func name is right.

Answer (score 0):

In the php manual site there is an example further down with this sentence.

> The two keys from the key => value pairs are considered equal only if (string) $key1 === (string) $key2 . In other words a strict type check is executed so the string representation must be the same.

Now that might mean that they need to be strict strings in order for this function to work.

Also found something else interesting in the new write up for php 5

> Changed __toString() to be called wherever applicable. The magic method __toString() will now be called in a string context, that is, anywhere an object is used as a string. The fallback of returning a string that contains the object identifier was dropped in PHP 5.2.0. It became problematic because an object identifier cannot be considered unique. This change will mean that your application is flawed if you have relied on the object identifier as a return value. An attempt to use that value as a string will now result in a catchable fatal error.

another line

> Even with __toString(), objects cannot be used as array indices or keys. We may add built-in hash support for this at a later date, but as of PHP 5.2.x you will need to either provide your own hashing or use the new SPL function spl_object_hash(). Exceptions can not be thrown from __toString() methods.

Quoted from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.incompatible.php).

Comment: My keys are numerical (int), aren't they?

Comment: yes but if you read more in there it says it also compares the values also. So it means that you can't use it if your values also cant be evaluated to a strict string type. This function seems to need more documentation of its behavior on the site.

Comment: See my edits... added code don't fail even using anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should compare only keys but apparently not.

So you should add a [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) method to your class.

EDIT : off topic, my answer should be deleted